# Rails 3: Application not picking up image files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, routes

Bit of a newbie question. I can't seem to get my application to pick up images 
that I have in a local folder ( public/stylesheets/images/XYZ/*.png). As a result
my main page is rendered without some essential graphics.

In my HAML file, I have  tags defined as follows: 
   %img{:src => '/images/XYZ/scissor.png'}

This leads to calls like: 
Started GET "/images/dookum.in/scissor.png' for 127.0.0.1 ....

and error messages like: 
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/images/dookum.in/scissor.png')

I don't know why this is happening. Do I need to define RAILS_ROOT? Or change routes.rb? If yes, then how?

Thanks for your help
Abhinav

Comment: is that happening on development version too?

Comment: You say they are in `/stylesheets/images/XYZ/`, but you are searching them in `/images/dookum.in/` (no stylesheets). Is a mistake on the post, or is this inconsistency what's preventing the images from being found?

Answer (score 1):

You may try to add following setting in your environment files

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Comment: This is true if he had a problem in production. As far as i know, this setting is by default true in development mode.

Answer (score 0):

Either you write

```
= image_tag('scissor.png')
```

and this will look for the file `/public/images/scissor.png`, or you should specify `stylesheets/images/XYZ/...`

Everything under `/public` is served in development mode, if you want you rails process to serve everything under `/public` in production-mode, you have to set the `config.serve_static_assets` to true.